# Windows Forms application on Windows 10 tablets?

Tags: windows, vb.net

As part of an internship project, I am looking to deploy an application on PC (Windows 10) as well as on mobile digital media such as tablets. 
I have some programming knowledge in VB.Net and have the Visual Basic 2010 Express IDE. Is a Windows Forms Application executable on Windows 10 tablets? If yes, are there compatibility issues (e.g. tactile events)? I am looking for the most suitable equipment for daily use for production monitoring operations. All the devices must have access to the same database to draw up daily reports from a master tool (a PC).

Comment: You can run a Windows Forms app on any Windows 10 machine. Even Windows 10 S can run a WinForms app, if you run it through Project Centennial. Windows Forms was designed well before touch input was common though, so it's not really ideal. You'd have to think about control size and spacing fairly carefully, although I use WinForms apps with just touch without major issue. WPF would be a better option though, and UWP better again. That will take more learning though, plus you'd have to use a newer VS version. VS 2017 Community is free. Is that an option?

Comment: There were some tablet models that tried to buy into UWP but they did not last long.  You can't be sure you won't get stuck with such a reject, so write a basic "hello world" test app and try it out.  Only real concern is to design your UI so it can be operated with fat fingers.  So big buttons and nothing like a NumericUpDown control or anything that requires a right-click.

Comment: "There were some tablet models that tried to buy into UWP but they did not last long". That sentence doesn't really make sense. Individual tablet models don't "buy into" UWP or not. Any Windows 10 device can run UWP apps, whether they are tablets or not. That means that every Windows 10 tablet can and will run UWP apps.

Comment: Winforms applications do run on Windows 10 tablets. If developed with Visual Studio 2017 and a Bridge project is added to the solution, they can be deployed through Microsoft store. Winforms applications can receive Metro/WPF look&feel by applying third party form managers like metroframework-modern-ui .

Comment: Develop an UWP app might be a great solution for ergonomic reasons as you said and get a newer VS version isn't a problem. Can i still code with VB ? I don't have any knowledge on C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is a Windows Forms Application executable on Windows 10 tablets?

Yes, Windows 10 tablets are able to run traditional Win32/.NET desktop applications. Please refer to the following article for more information about this: https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-arm-not-windows-rt.

As mentioned in the comments, you should be aware of the fact that tablet users may excpect a more touch friendly UI compared to what a traditional Windows Forms application may offer by default though.

If you intend to target only Windows 10+, you might want to to take a look at the [Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide).

Comment: Finally, I decided to develop a WPF app and it runs great on Windows 10 tablets.Thanks for your response.